# Sending big data to server, Cross-Domain

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-domain

I'm trying to send chunks of data from many different servers my app is on, to mine.
Using some dummy image source, passing my data as a GET query. (*img.gif?aaa=xxx&bb=yyy...*)
the Query is many times too long and gets cut.

is there some better way for me to send the data cross-browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be the best if you used POST method when sending the data.

```
 var msgSender = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
 msgSender.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 msgSender.setRequestHeader("Encoding", "Windows-1257")     
 msgSender.open("POST", "http://yourderver/page" ,true);
 msgSender.onreadystatechange = function(){...};
 var msg = "your very long message goes here";

 //preparing post data
 var strToSend = "someotherarg=somevalue" + username;
     strToSend+= "&msg=" + msg;
 strToSend = escape(strToSend);
 msgSender.send(strToSend);
```

The solution is even easier, if you use jQuery - just call `$.post()` method: http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post

EDIT:
However, this will not work cross-domain, unless you specify ['Access-Control'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTTP_access_control) headers on your server and the clients have modern enouhg browsers (FireFox 3.5+ etc)

So, another solution is to include a hidden IFRAME in your page (the page lives on your server then) which contains a form and you call Submit() of that form to POST the data.

Comment: hidden iframe? and how would the data go to iframe if the query is too long? anyway, that would be 2 HTTP requests each time...

Comment: If the iframe is from your domain, you can access its DOM using javascript! `document.getElementById("yourframe").document.forms[0].submit()` etc!

Comment: I know, but as I said already, the data is crossed-domain. this is it. iframe trick won't help a bit..

Comment: It is not a problem to submit a normal HTML form to a different domain than yours! Or... don't I get the problem?

Comment: so why did you said in your edit "the page lives on your server "... I like your iframe idea :)

Comment: I said it because - if you had your "base page" on `http://server1` and made an `<iframe src='http://server2'>`, then you could not access the iframe from javaScript due to cross-domain restrictions

Answer (score 0):

Split your payload (e.g. at 1024 bytes), then send using several GET requests.

Comment: That's what I thought doing, although it seems a bit of an ugly solution to me :/

Comment: Ugly indeed; but with AJAX POST, the [Same Origin Policy][1] will block you; and although [RFC2616][2] says "The HTTP protocol does not place any a priori limit on the length of a URI", [some user agents][3] are pretty sure that 2083 bytes ought to be enough for everybody.

  [1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy
  [2]: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.2.1
  [3]: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208427